# What element is slotable?

Tags: html, shadow-dom, custom-element, slot, native-web-component

Can I use a tr (table row) for a named slot?
And what happend when I use a tr as a slot's fallback content?

like this:

```
<x-table>
    <tr slot="x-row">
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
</x-table>
```

sample code in codepen https://codepen.io/JJia/pen/odXrWJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `<tr>` element must have a [parent among `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>` or `<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr) elements.

Unfortunately, these elements cannot support a Shadow DOM. See the list of [elements with the `attachShadow()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow).

As a consequence, their first-level childs (i.e. `<tr>`) cannot be used with a `slot` attribute.

Comment: Is there any workaround?

Comment: A workaround: create your own custom element wrapper that will detect your slotet content and me it in a working container.

Comment: Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56354946/4600982