# How to pass option tags to a custom element as distributed nodes (aka <slot></slot>)

Tags: shadow-dom, slot

I have a web component custom element defined like so.

```
 <template id="dropdown-template">
        <select>
            <slot></slot>
        </select>
    </template>
    <script>
        class Dropdown extends HTMLElement {
            constructor() {
                super();
                const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
                let template = document.getElementById('dropdown-template');
                shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
            }
        }
        customElements.define("drop-down", Dropdown);
    </script>
```

When trying to use it, I try and pass option tags with values into the custom element.

```
<drop-down>
     <option>one</option>
     <option>two</option>
     <option>three</option>
</drop-down>
```

This doesn't work. The select element is shown to have a `<slot>` element as its direct child, and it doesn't render the options. Is this not possible to do with the `<select>` tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It not possible to do it like that because the parent element of an `<option>` tag must be a `<select>` tag. So you can use  with Shadow DOM because the `<slot>` element will break the parent/child hierachy.

**Solution 1 : move elements**

A workaround is to move the content of the light DOM inside the `<select>` element in the template.

```js
class Dropdown extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow( {mode: 'open'} )
        let template = document.getElementById( 'dropdown-template' )
        shadowRoot.appendChild( template.content.cloneNode(true) )

        const select = shadowRoot.querySelector( 'select' )     
        shadowRoot.addEventListener( 'slotchange', ev => {      
            let node = this.querySelector( 'option' )
            node && select.append( node )
        } )
    }
}
customElements.define("drop-down", Dropdown);
```

```html
<template id="dropdown-template">
    <select></select>
    <slot></slot>
</template>

<drop-down>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
</drop-down>
```

**Solution 2: customized `<select>`**

Another possibility is to avoid Shadow DOM and define your drop-down list as a customized built-in `<select>` element. Maybe this won't fit your needs if you want to customize the layout.

```
<select is="drop-down">
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>tree</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Another solution is to make your own select/option system without using the native select/option elements. Ugh. Spec writers should just fix this stuff. Introduce new rules somehow?