# Using <slot> in native <select> element

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom

I am trying to create an "enhanced" `select` element by slotting contents using Shadow dom into it.
This is the file (the full code is in in [Glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/time-exception):

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element'
export class Select extends LitElement {
  render () {
    return html`
      <select id="_native">
        <slot></slot>
      </select>
`
  }
}
customElements.define('nn-select', Select)
```

However, nothing seems to get slotted.
Renaming `select` into `select2` "solves" the problem.

Is there a limitation so that we cannot `<slot>` into native elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there a limitation: a `<select>` element accepts only `<option>` elements as children. As a consequence, you cannot use `<slot>`.

Same limitation with `<tr>` and `<td>`...

See this other [SO post on the same subject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56351274/4600982).