# get value from selected option in web component

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom, lit-element

I'm trying to get the value of my selected option, so when someone uses my web component they can access it. I think the problem has to do with the shadow root

```
__createOptions() {
    const SELECT = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('select');
    SELECT.addEventListener('change', event => {
        this.value= event.target.value;
    });
    this.shadowRoot.addEventListener('slotchange', () => {
        const OPTION = this.querySelector('option');
        if (OPTION) {
            SELECT.append(OPTION);
        }
    });
}

render() {
    return html`
    <div class="selectWrapper">
        <select id="typeDropdown"></select>
    </div>
    <slot></slot>
`;
}

  <wc-select value="">
   <option value="1">Option 1</option>
   <option value"2">Option 2</option>
   <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </wc-select>
```

Comment: You can not **slot** ``option`` into a ``select`` see duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57878970/using-slot-in-native-select-element

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I don't have the slot inside of the select and the question is not related to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was too quick in my comment.

### `<SLOTs>` can not be targeted like 'normal' DOM elements

> (like many) You are running into the trap of thinking **slotted** content
> is **MOVED** to ShadowDOM `<slots>`

It is **NOT**.

> **slotted** content is only **REFLECTED** in shadowDOM, it still remains *invisible!* in lightDOM

You can **not** access the **reflected** content with `.querySelector` or `.children[]`
... because it is not there (in shadowDOM).. it still is in lightDOM.

For the same reason you style slotted content in lightDOM:
[Use CSS selectors like :first-child inside shadow dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61237571/use-css-selectors-like-first-child-inside-shadow-dom)

---

#### To append lightDOM `<OPTIONs>` into a shadowDOM `` <SELECT`> ``

**1. You either move them from lightDOM to shadowDOM:**

```
    let select = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('select');
    let host = this.shadowRoot.getRootNode().host;
    let options = host.querySelectorAll('option');
    select.append(...options);
```

#1 is the easiest one, as it does not require any `<slots>` in shadowDOM

**2. You were on the right track with the `slotchange` event**
it requires a (named/unnamed) `<slot></slot>` in the shadowDOM template.
You find your lightDOM nodes in:

- [MDN: assignedNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSlotElement/assignedNodes)
- [MDN: assignedElements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSlotElement/assignedElements)

BE AWARE, this gets you ALL [nodeTypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) including `text` nodes because there are linebreaks and whitespace in the `<my-element>` innerHTML!

```
    <my-element>
      <option>Grow up</option>
      <option>Learn React</option>
      <option>Learn Lit</option>
      <option>Forget W3C standard Custom Elements API</option>
      <H1 slot=title>My Never Todo List</hH>
    </my-element>
```

Luckily the `<SELECT>` doesn't care, so you can dump `assignedNodes` straight in..

```
    this.shadowRoot.addEventListener('slotchange', (evt) => {
      if (!evt.target.name) { // only for unnamed slot
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector('select')
            .append(...evt.target.assignedNodes());
      }
    });
```

**note!** The `<options>` were **reflected** to the UNnamed slot,
`<H1 slot=title>` **reflected** to the `<slot name=title>`

(they should have named them *reflections* instead of *slots*)

Click Show Code Snippet for complete code

```js
customElements.define("my-element", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    let template = document.getElementById(this.nodeName);
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    }).append(template.content.cloneNode(true));

    this.shadowRoot.addEventListener('slotchange', (evt) => {
      if (!evt.target.name) { // only for unnamed slot
        let select = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('select');
        select.append(...evt.target.assignedNodes());
      }
    });

  }
})
```

```html
<template id=MY-ELEMENT>
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }

    select{
      font-size:1.5em;
    }

  </style>
  <slot name=title></slot>
  <select multiple>
  </select>
  <slot></slot>
</template>

<my-element>
  <option>Grow up</option>
  <option>Learn React</option>
  <option>Learn Lit</option>
  <option>Forget W3C standard Custom Elements API</option>
  <h1 slot=title>My Never Todo List</h1>
</my-element>
```

**JSFiddle playground with both options:
https://jsfiddle.net/CustomElementsExamples/v2f9zmu5/**

---

More SLOT related answers can be found with StackOverflow Search: [Custom Elements SLOTs](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22Custom-Elements-SLOTs%22&so=uri&tab=newest)

Comment: Thanks so much for you. answer Danny. I'm runing into the issue where if someone uses my web component "my-element" how can they get the value of the ``select``. Assuming the user has no access to component's logic. So they are just going to import the component in their project and start using it

Comment: with ``mode:"open"`` they can always access ``document.querySelector('my-element').shadowRoot.querySelector('select')``. or add a method that returns a pointer to ``<select>``. But IMHO you should abstract all things do-able with ``<select>`` to attributes (and maybe extra methods) on ``<my-element>``

Comment: This would be a lot easier with **Customized Built-In Elements** (extending ``HTMLSelectElement``) instead of **Autonomous Elements** (extending ``HTMLElement``) But [Apple refuses to implement Customized Built-In Elements](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4670146924773376). So if you do **not** have to deliver to Safari you can extend SELECT (supported in all other Browsers)