# How to repeat outer DOM for all the slottables in a slot?

Tags: native-web-component

I want to have a web component which accepts N children, and displays them in a list format. I discovered that I can declare N slots with the same name and they will be added as siblings of each other, like so:

```js
window.customElements.define('x-list', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor () {
    super();
    const template = document.querySelector('#x-list').content;
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    shadow.appendChild(template.cloneNode(true));
  }
});
```

```html
<x-list>
  <li slot="item">Item 1</li>
  <li slot="item">Item 2</li>
  <li slot="item">Item 3</li>
</x-list>

<template id="x-list">
  <ul>
    <slot name="item">Items go here</slot>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Which works out ok. But I don't want to bleed implementation details, so I was looking for other approaches to this. Ideally, people using the component would only need to provide N elements, and the wrapping into a list would happen in the innards of the component itself.

- Changing the code so that there's a `<li>` inside the `<ul>` in the template fails trivially because all the slotables go into the same `<li>`element.
- Setting `role="listitem"` on the `<slot>` inside the `<ul>` fails because attributes set on the `<slot>` are not copied into the slotables.
- Adding a `slotchange` event listener to the `<slot>` and setting `role="listitem"` for every assigned Node does work, but it means the web component is messing with the provided Nodes, which does not seem appropriate.
- Going into the `slotchange` event and trying to mess with the assigned Nodes, so I can dynamically wrap them around newly created `<li>` elements, requires that I remove them from their place in the DOM. So it not only messes with user-provided markup but it also triggers new occurrences of the `slotchange` event.

Is there any other way to do this without leaking implementation details of the custom element?

Comment: the best solution is to listen for slotchange events and move the elements in the shadow dom

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass option tags to a custom element as distributed nodes (aka <slot></slot>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56351274/how-to-pass-option-tags-to-a-custom-element-as-distributed-nodes-aka-slot-sl)

Comment: @Supersharp Not really, that's a different problem. But in the meanwhile, I've found a kind-of solution, so I'll write a self-answer asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a bit about how others seem to be using web components, I've found a partially acceptable solution: using 2 web-components, instead of 1; one for the list, and one for the list items.

Or in snippet form:

```js
window.customElements.define('x-list', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor () {
    super();
    const template = document.querySelector('#x-list').content;
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    shadow.appendChild(template.cloneNode(true));
  }
});

window.customElements.define('x-list-item', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor () {
    super();
    const template = document.querySelector('#x-list-item').content;
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    shadow.appendChild(template.cloneNode(true));
  }
});
```

```html
<template id="x-list">
  <ul>
    <slot></slot>
  </ul>
</template>

<template id="x-list-item">
   <li role="listitem">
     <slot>List item</slot>
   </li>
</template>

<x-list>
  <x-list-item>Item 1</x-list-item>
  <x-list-item>Item 2</x-list-item>
  <x-list-item>Item 3</x-list-item>
</x-list>
```

Which works correctly, except that the template for `x-list-item` does, in fact, need the `role="listitem"` attribute added to the `<li>` elements.

If I don't add the `role` attribute, the Firefox Accessibility Tools refuse to interpret the `<li>` as `listitem`, and marks them as `text container` instead. I have no idea if this is a browser-specific bug, or a side effect of something I don't quite understand, but at least it seems to be working correctly.

The following is an image showing the accessibility tree of:

1. A native `<ul>`and `<li>` list
2. My solution, without `role="listitem"` on the `<li>` elements
3. My solution, with `role="listitem"` on the `<li>` elements

[image: The resulting accessibility tree for the 3 different lists]

If anyone has any information regarding this behaviour, I'd love to know, but for now, I'll accept this solution because:

1. It avoids leaking implementation details; from a library point of view, both can be internally changed without this affecting user code
2. It avoids any JavaScript magic that has to run every time the content changes, users can add and remove `<x-list-item>` and the browser does all the work
3. It results in an acceptable accessibility tree (there are slight differences between this and the native `<ul>` and `<li>`, but they're not different enough that I consider it a problem)